# how to return to original binary file after converting with xxd

Tags: vim

When editing the file in vim  ,i  input `:%!xxd` to check  the ascii.

```
:%!xxd
```

Vim  quit if i input `:q`.

```
:q
```

I  want to return to the previous file to continue my work.
How can i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:%!xxd -r` to return back to normal mode

Answer (score 1):

`%!xxd -r` will work if you have not made changes or if you would like to save the changes.

If you would like to disregard any changes you could do something like

```
:e! %
```

or just undo until you get your original file